# Builtin Ruby or ActiveSupport function for "select first n elements satisfying a predicate"?

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I'm looking for a `select` that "short-circuits" once it's returned a certain number of items:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].select_first(1) { |x| x.odd? }
[1]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].select_first(2) { |x| x.odd? }
[1, 3]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].select_first(1000) { |x| x.odd? }
[1, 3, 5]
```

Is there a library function, either in core or in ActiveSupport, that does this? It's easy to roll my own, but I thought I would check.

Note that I do not want `select { ... }.take(n)` because the block might have side effects.

Comment: What kind of side effects are you worried about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].lazy.select{|x| x.odd? }.take(n).to_a
```

But if you want to avoid `select{ . . }.take(n)` you could also do:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each{|x| arr << x if x.odd?; break if arr.count == n}
```

Comment: if you use `first(n)` instead of `take(n)` you can do away with `to_a`

Comment: second example I believe you meant `arr.count` as `x` is a `Fixnum` and does not have a `count` method.